# Centrar texto dentro de un contenedor (no sirve text-align:center; ni align-items:center;)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Creé un enlace dentro de un contenedor, el contenedor tiene grid. 
Ya usé `text-align:center;` y `align-items:center;` pero nada me funciona, quiero que el "Saber mas" se centre al contenedor ¿Porqué no sirve ninguna de estas etiquetas? Estoy usando un selector para el "boton" que es `.saber-mas{}` intenté poniendo ahí dentro las etiquetas ya mencionadas pero nada, igual creé otro selector `.tejuino-principal` a `{}` y de igual manera poner las etiquetas, pero nada. Gracias

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Public Sans';
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 2;
    background-image: url("../img/background.jpeg");
    background-size: COVER;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Globales */

.contenedor {
    max-width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.centrar-texto {
    text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}

.saber-mas {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.saber-mas:hover {
    color: red;
    transition: .2s;
}


/* Globales */


/* Menu de navegación */

.logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.contenedor-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

.navegacion-principal a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
    color: white;
}

.navegacion-principal {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3rem;
}

.navegacion-principal a:hover {
    color: blue;
}


/* Menu de navegación */

.titulo {
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -8rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    text-shadow: .2rem .2rem white;
}


/* RASPADO-PRINCIPAL */

.raspados-principal img {
    padding: 1.5rem
}

.raspados-principal {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);
}

.texto-raspados {
    padding-right: 2rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.texto-raspados h2 {
    color: rgb(12, 180, 96);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem red;
}

.almibar {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.texto-raspados a:hover {
    color: red;
}


/* RASPADO-PRINCIPAL */


/* TEJUINO PRINCIPAL */

.tejuino-principal {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.tejuino-principal a {
    
}

.tejuino-principal img {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: ;
}

.texto-tejuino {
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}

.texto-tejuino h2 {
    color: rgb(12, 180, 96);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem red;
}


/* TEJUINO PRINCIPAL */


/* TEPACHE PRINCIPAL */

.tepache-principal {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.tepache-principal img {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}


/* TEPACHE PRINCIPAL */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One|Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Public+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Raspados Isla</title>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="contenedor-nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="/img/logoo copia.png" alt="Logo Raspados Isla">
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav class="navegacion-principal">
            <a href="#" class="verde">Raspados</a>
            <a href="#" class="verde">Tejuino</a>
            <a href="#" class="blanco">Tepache</a>
            <a href="#" class="rojo">Tuba</a>
            <a href="#" class="rojo">Cerveza De Raíz</a>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <h1 class="titulo">PRODUCTOS ARTESANALES</h1>

    <main class="contenedor">
        <section class="raspados-principal">
            <img src="/img/diablitoo3.jpg" alt="Foto Diablito">
            <div class="texto-raspados">
                <h2>Los Raspados, Una tradicion muy Mexicana</h2>
                </p>
                Es un postre helado que consiste en mezclar hielo raspado con <a href="#" class="almibar">almibar</a> puedes elegir entre diferentes sabores de almibares, desde tan dulces que haran explotar tus papilas gustativas hasta sabores picosos
                y acidos que te pondran a llorar. Sin duda el Chamoy es uno de los "dulces" mas representativos y conocidos en Mexico ¡tanto asi que hasta los niños de 3 años lo comen! y no puedes pasar un dia mas sin probar nuestro representativo Diablito!
                elaborado con nuestro propio Chamoy. Para el Diablito puedes elegir entre diferentes sabores como son: Limon, Fresa, Mango, Piña, Tamarindo o Nanche despues de haberte decidido le ponemos hielo raspado, el almibar, jugo de limon natural,
                Tajin, polvo Miguelito, sal de grano y una banderilla de Tamarindo <br> <a href="#" class="saber-mas">Saber más</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- raspados-->
        </section>
        <section class="tejuino-principal">
            <img src="/img/tejuinochido.jpg" alt="Foto Tejuino">
            <div class="texto-tejuino">
                <h2>Tejuino, bebida de los Dioses</h2>
                <p>
                    El nombre Tejuino viene de la palabra náhuatl tecuín que significa latir. <br> El Tejuino es una bebida refrescante elaborada con Maíz, Piloncillo, Azucar moscabada, entre otros ingredientes. Se fermenta un par de dias y se sirve con
                    hielo, limon y sal en grano, la mezcla de estos ingredientes le da un toque agridulce perfecto para combatir el calor. Esta bebida proviene del norte de México que ademas de tener un delicioso sabor es benificioso para la salud ya
                    que cuenta con probióticos. Entre algunos pueblos del norte de México como los yaquis y tarahumaras, se prepara esta bebida con fines ceremoniales; la beben como ofrenda a las figuras sagradas, en fiestas que mezclan sus hermosas tradiciones
                    con el catolicismo. <br> <a href="#" class="saber-mas">Saber más</a>
                </p>


            </div>
            <!--Tejuino-->
        </section>
        <section class="tepache-principal">
            <img src="/img/Tepache.jpg" alt="Foto Tepache">
            <div class="texto-tepache">
                <h2>Tepache</h2>
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es englobar cada uno de los enlaces dentro de un div para que ocupe todo el espacio de su div contenedor (al tener por defecto la propiedad `display: block`) y en este div utilizar la propiedad `text-align: center` para centrar el enlace dentro de ese espacio.

```
.contenedorEnlace{
  text-align: center;
}
```

**NOTA:** Fíjate en que el primer párrafo lo empiezas con la etiqueta de cierre `</p>` y que he movido las etiquetas de cierre de los dos párrafos justo antes del enlace (para dejar al div fuera del párrafo).

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Public Sans';
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 2;
    background-image: url("../img/background.jpeg");
    background-size: COVER;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Globales */

.contenedor {
    max-width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.centrar-texto {
    text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}

.saber-mas {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.saber-mas:hover {
    color: red;
    transition: .2s;
}


/* Globales */


/* Menu de navegación */

.logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.contenedor-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

.navegacion-principal a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
    color: white;
}

.navegacion-principal {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3rem;
}

.navegacion-principal a:hover {
    color: blue;
}


/* Menu de navegación */

.titulo {
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -8rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    text-shadow: .2rem .2rem white;
}


/* RASPADO-PRINCIPAL */

.raspados-principal img {
    padding: 1.5rem
}

.raspados-principal {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);
}

.texto-raspados {
    padding-right: 2rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.texto-raspados h2 {
    color: rgb(12, 180, 96);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem red;
}

.almibar {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.texto-raspados a:hover {
    color: red;
}


/* RASPADO-PRINCIPAL */


/* TEJUINO PRINCIPAL */

.tejuino-principal {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.tejuino-principal a {
    
}

.tejuino-principal img {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: ;
}

.texto-tejuino {
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}

.texto-tejuino h2 {
    color: rgb(12, 180, 96);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem red;
}


/* TEJUINO PRINCIPAL */


/* TEPACHE PRINCIPAL */

.tepache-principal {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.726);
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.tepache-principal img {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}

.contenedorEnlace{
  text-align: center;
}

/* TEPACHE PRINCIPAL */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One|Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Public+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Raspados Isla</title>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="contenedor-nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="/img/logoo copia.png" alt="Logo Raspados Isla">
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav class="navegacion-principal">
            <a href="#" class="verde">Raspados</a>
            <a href="#" class="verde">Tejuino</a>
            <a href="#" class="blanco">Tepache</a>
            <a href="#" class="rojo">Tuba</a>
            <a href="#" class="rojo">Cerveza De Raíz</a>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <h1 class="titulo">PRODUCTOS ARTESANALES</h1>

    <main class="contenedor">
        <section class="raspados-principal">
            <img src="/img/diablitoo3.jpg" alt="Foto Diablito">
            <div class="texto-raspados">
                <h2>Los Raspados, Una tradicion muy Mexicana</h2>
                <p>
                Es un postre helado que consiste en mezclar hielo raspado con <a href="#" class="almibar">almibar</a> puedes elegir entre diferentes sabores de almibares, desde tan dulces que haran explotar tus papilas gustativas hasta sabores picosos
                y acidos que te pondran a llorar. Sin duda el Chamoy es uno de los "dulces" mas representativos y conocidos en Mexico ¡tanto asi que hasta los niños de 3 años lo comen! y no puedes pasar un dia mas sin probar nuestro representativo Diablito!
                elaborado con nuestro propio Chamoy. Para el Diablito puedes elegir entre diferentes sabores como son: Limon, Fresa, Mango, Piña, Tamarindo o Nanche despues de haberte decidido le ponemos hielo raspado, el almibar, jugo de limon natural,
                Tajin, polvo Miguelito, sal de grano y una banderilla de Tamarindo <br></p> <div class="contenedorEnlace"><a href="#" class="saber-mas">Saber más</a></div>
                
            </div>
            <!-- raspados-->
        </section>
        <section class="tejuino-principal">
            <img src="/img/tejuinochido.jpg" alt="Foto Tejuino">
            <div class="texto-tejuino">
                <h2>Tejuino, bebida de los Dioses</h2>
                <p>
                    El nombre Tejuino viene de la palabra náhuatl tecuín que significa latir. <br> El Tejuino es una bebida refrescante elaborada con Maíz, Piloncillo, Azucar moscabada, entre otros ingredientes. Se fermenta un par de dias y se sirve con
                    hielo, limon y sal en grano, la mezcla de estos ingredientes le da un toque agridulce perfecto para combatir el calor. Esta bebida proviene del norte de México que ademas de tener un delicioso sabor es benificioso para la salud ya
                    que cuenta con probióticos. Entre algunos pueblos del norte de México como los yaquis y tarahumaras, se prepara esta bebida con fines ceremoniales; la beben como ofrenda a las figuras sagradas, en fiestas que mezclan sus hermosas tradiciones
                    con el catolicismo. <br></p><div class="contenedorEnlace"> <a href="#" class="saber-mas">Saber más</a></div>
                


            </div>
            <!--Tejuino-->
        </section>
        <section class="tepache-principal">
            <img src="/img/Tepache.jpg" alt="Foto Tepache">
            <div class="texto-tepache">
                <h2>Tepache</h2>
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ya puse las nuevas etiquetas, el problema es que crece todo el ancho, y yo quiero que este pequeño, le cambie el display: inline-block; pero no puedo centrar el boton al texto, por que pasa esto? background-color: rgb(16, 148, 165);
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 .2rem red;

Comment: @Jorge He editado mi respuesta para que el enlace solo ocupe la parte del texto. La clave es englobarlo en un div para que este ocupe todo el ancho y centrarlo desde este. También fíjate en que algunas etiquetas las he cambiado (como indico en la respuesta). El `inline-block` es ligeramente diferente al `block`, ya que lo que significa es que se comporta como un elemento inline pero le puedes dar propiedades como top, bottom, left,etc... que a un elemento inline por defecto no le puedes dar. Sin embargo, el inline-block al actuar como un elemento inline no ocupa todo el espacio por defecto.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya lo logre, me estaba rompiendo la cabeza!

Comment: Veo, Francisco, que hace casi un año que no publicas. ¿Puedo preguntar el porqué? Pura curiosidad. No sé si tiene que ver con el tema de SE echando a moderadores, luego CM...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Sí, principalmente fue por eso. No me gustó nada como se gestionó el tema y creo que era la mejor forma de apoyar. La verdad que en el momento si que estuve bastante pendiente pero ahora desconozco como finalizó la cosa. Me fastidia por la gente que viene aquí a tener una respuesta válida en español y, aunque si que me meto de vez en cuando a curiosear, ya no me sale el responder. Me duele que lo hayan gestionado tan tan mal.

Comment: Eres un grande, Francisco. Muchos hemos tenido las mismas dudas, uno se siente entre la espada y la pared: desengañado con SE pero a la vez con la pena de no poder ayudar a gente que entra en la comunidad. La cosa empeoró, pues también echaron a unos cuantos CM de los veteranos. Alguna gente ha montado una estructura nueva llamada [Codidact](https://codidact.org), yo últimamente la estoy visitando más. Un abrazo.

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar display:flex para que puedas usar align-items solo recuerda que las dos instrucciones las debe llevar el padre del contenido que quieres centrar, pero en este caso align-items no es el adecuado por que sirve para alinear verticalmente, lo que estas buscando es justify-content, lo que es similar a align-text, pero sirve para cualquier contenido sea texto o elemento html, también es importante saber que depende si el padre de nuestro elemento esta acomodando a nuestro elemento de la forma que queremos, por lo que sería necesario repetir las mismas instrucciones

```css
#div1{
dispay:flex
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
}   /*acomoda #div2, en el centro de #div1*/
#div2{
dispay:flex
justify-content: center;
}/*acomoda p, en el centro de #div2*/

p{
dispay:flex
justify-content: center;
}/*acomoda el texto, en el centro de p*/
```

```html
<div id="div1">
 <div id="div2">
  <p>hola</p>
 </div>
</div>
```